# rxjs: Awaiting an httpGet call with pipes

Tags: typescript, async-await, rxjs, observable, http-get

This issue has popped up a couple of times, and every time it does I scramble to figure out how to do it the right way, since I can never seem how to find how I did it last time when I need it.

This time it came up because I realized I need to do an extra `httpGet` call when processing a previous `httpGet` call:

```
http.getWrapper<T>(whatever)
  .pipe<T, T>(map<T, T>(res => getWrapper2<T, T>(res)) // New function, returns the same type it was given
  .pipe<T, U>(oldStuff)
```

The issue that I'm having is that previously, without the extra `get` call, my `oldStuff` handler received a `T` that it could handle without issue. But the new `get` call returns an `Observable<T>`, and I always find it confusing to figure out how to tell the pipe chain to wait for the `get` to finish, and use the final value. Anything I can think of doing, which mostly seems to be variations of `toPromise()` and `async/await`, just move the extra layer between me and my data around, and I can't quite seem to get to it. For some reason inserting this second `get` just always seems to be more confusing than the first `get` was, and I don't know if I need a structure change or it's just my thinking is off.

To make things even more confusing, the extra layer of processing is only sometimes needed:

```
.pipe(map(res => condition(res) ? getWrapper2(res) : res))
```

What can I do to await and flatten this so I can pass the new `get` result to the rest of the `pipe` chain?

Comment: What I understand from your problem statement is,Two `http` call needs to make and request of 2nd `http.get` is depend on response of 1st `http.get` and you wnat them in chain,right?

Answer (score 5):

you are looking for `high order observables`

the most popular operators:
`mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap`

These operators should return observable and in the next step you will receive data

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const initialApiCall = () => of('initialApiCall');
const extraApiCall = (res) => of(res + '_' + 'extra result'); // getWrapper2
const condition = (res) => !res;

initialApiCall()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((res) => (condition(res) // checking condition
     ? extraApiCall(res) // api call
     : of(res)) // should convert privitive data to observable
    ),
    map((data) => console.log(data)) // here you will have result of `extraApiCall` or `res`
  )
  .subscribe();
```

DEMO:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-suryq3?file=index.ts

Comment: please mark as correct if it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
 url_users = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
 url_posts = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  this.http
      .get(this.url_users)
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => console.log('users- ', res)),
        concatMap((users) => this.http.get(this.url_posts + '/' + users[3].id))
      )
      .subscribe({
         next: (posts) => {
             console.log(posts);
         },
         error: (err) => console.log(err),
      });
```

> - concatMap subscribes to the inner Observable (In our case 2nd    `http.get`) and sends its output to the result Observable
> - concatMap will wait for previous HTTP Observable to complete before    mapping the new value to an HTTP Observable, subscribing to it and
>   therefore triggering the next get

**you will find more about [Higher-Order RxJs Mapping Operators: switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap (and exhaustMap)](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)**